# Event Handler procedure to record all values in a selection of cells before and after they are changed

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I am trying to create an automatic procedure which will be activated every time a user changes the values in a cell on a worksheet.  I have managed to create a procedure that will record the value if one cell is changed, but if the user pastes in several cells then only the first cell which they selected will be changed. This is what I have so far, any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Dim OldCellValue As String

' Get Windows Username
Function Usernam() As String
    Usernam = Environ("username")
End Function

' Record the current cell value.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    OldCellValue = ActiveCell.Text
End Sub

'Paste the original value and new value into the next free row on sheet3
'with Windows username, date and time     
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Lstrow As Long
Dim Changerow As Long

    Lstrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Lstrow).Value = Usernam
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & Lstrow).Value = Date
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & Lstrow).Value = Time
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & Lstrow).Value = "Sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & _
        ", Range " & Target.Address & " Chanaged from """ & OldCellValue & _
        """  to """ & Target.Value & """"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

This shows you how to use the Target range with multiple cells but it doesn't address the need you now have to potentially store a multiple prior cell range in memory

I have played with

- public variables to hold the prior range,
- then process the cells if the address of the `Selection` Target is identical to the `Change` Target but it is very kludgy

I think you need a different way to track the change - for example on the `Selection` add the current value to a cell comment. Still messy though, and any cell by cell changes will be very intensive for Excel if working with ranges ...

**Original Post**
You need to work with the `Target` range to work on each cell,ie

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For Each rng2 In Target
rng1.Resize(1, 4) = Array(Environ("username"), Date, Time, "Sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & _
        ", Range " & rng2.Address & " Changed from """ & OldCellValue & _
        """  to """ & rng2.Value & """")
Next rng2
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, this shows how to use the `Target` range with multiple cells but it doesn't address the need you now have to store a multiple prior cell range in memory